# Code not implemented trying to format text but its not working

Tags: html, css

```
<p id="texts">© 2021 Agam Gambhir @rerite.</p>
```

The above is the html part. I tried using `class` instead of `id` but it didn't work. I also tried editing all the paragraphs and it worked.

Here is my CSS:

```
#texts {
    color: white;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-family: 'Fredoka One';
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one element with id texts? Also, please say what didn’t work means, what did you see?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is do is 0.75.
Then check the font you are selected do work on your browser.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but could you provide a bit more detail into your answer as it is very unclear.